# How do I remove this gap caused by \Aboxed in the align environment?

Tags: align

I'm using `\Aboxed` to box my answers in the `align*` environment but sometimes there are huge gaps inline and others there are not. I'm pretty sure I happens when using sigma notation (`\sum`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

   \begin{align*}
e^x &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\\
e^x+2e^{-x} &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}
   \Aboxed{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\left(1+2(-1)^n\right)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Renders as:

[image]

How do I get rid of the gap?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by having /Aboxed defined, sorry.

Comment: Here it is on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/hjsfctdjpwkn

Comment: AFAIK, Aboxed uses mathrools, not amsmath. The above code block compiles correctly in Overleaf with the same output (same gap)

Comment: `\Aboxed` stands for "aligned boxed", aka it involves alignment and sort of expect a & inside the argument (the alignment point). Here you're not using alignment inside the box and you should use the normal boxed as AboAmmar mentions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\boxed` for this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  e^x &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\\
  e^x+2e^{-x} &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}
  \boxed{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\left(1+2(-1)^n\right)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]